# Gant build scripting, how to retrieve a task that I want to execute

Tags: grails, code-coverage, task, gant, jacoco

This is in grails, but I don't think anything specific to grails applies.

I have a Gant script that looks something like this:

```
includeTargets << grailsScript( "Init" )
includeTargets << grailsScript( "TestApp" )

target(main: "run tests with jacoco code coverage...") {  
     taskdef ( name:'coverage', classname:'org.jacoco.ant.CoverageTask', classpathref:'core.classpath' )
     coverage(*** NEED TO PUT RUN-TESTS TASK HERE ***)
}

setDefaultTarget(main)
```

The idea is I'm trying to run some unit tests with jacoco code coverage.  The target to run the tests is defined in TestApp.groovy ( allTests() ) and can be imported and run just fine, but the coverage task from jacoco wants the allTests() task added to it as a child task.  It needs to "wrap" the task to run the tests.  The Ant xml equivalent for what I'm trying to do is this:

```
<jacoco:coverage>
    <taskToRunTheTests ... >
        < ... setup ... >
    </taskToRunTheTests>
</jacoco:coverage>
```

So I guess what I'm looking for is a way, in Gant, to get a Task from a target definition, and pass it along to the coverage task (I can do coverageTask.addChild(theRunTestsTask) ... coverageTask.execute() if necessary).

This is an obscure one, hope somebody can help we with it.

Comment: Did you perhaps find a solution for this problem? I am trying to achieve exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working, this doesn't exactly answer your specific question but the original idea; to have jacoco-produced coverage for junit tests within a gant build. I couldn't get the jacoco:coverage working so I did it with the jacoco agent; something like this:

Setting up the agent:

```
import static groovy.xml.NamespaceBuilder.newInstance as namespace
def jacoco = namespace(ant, 'antlib:org.jacoco.ant')
```

...

```
jacoco.agent(property: 'agentvmparam', destfile: "$dirs.projDir\\target\\jacoco.exec", includes: '*', output: 'file', dumponexit: 'true')
```

...

and at this point we need to pass the `agentvmparam` to the JVM running junit;

```
jvmarg(value:"${agentvmparam}")
```

And it's working like a charm.